# locationmanager didenterregion doesn't get called

Tags: core-location, ibeacon

Supposing my code looks like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
               inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    //Handle beacons found during ranging

}

-(void)initBeaconRegion
{

    NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];

    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID major:345 minor:678 identifier:@"MyBeaconIdentifier"];
    self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = NO; //Used for Monitoring
    self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES; //Used for Monitoring
    self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES; //Used for Monitoring

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;

        //now start ranging
//        [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self initBeaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    NSLog(@"monitored regions %@",self.locationManager.monitoredRegions);
}
```

and some iPad app called xBeacon advertising with the same UUID, major and minor, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Should I approach the advertising device with the app, or wait longer?

Tried the same with Estimote beacon app, and both apps work as I check it on Beacon Scanner on my Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting a beacon monitoring callback to get called, but you aren't starting monitoring -- you are starting *ranging*.  Try changing this line:

```
   [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

to:

```
   [self.locationManager startMonitoringRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

Also, you need to set `self.locationManager.delegate = self` as @luca-corti suggests.

If you still don't get the callback, try using my [Locate app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8) to verify your test beacon is actually transmitting with the identifiers you expect.

Comment: no luck with the startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion (no declared selectors in Xcode), however your app sees it correctly

Comment: Also, double check your beacon identifiers and make sure they are exactly right.  If you are getting empty ranging callbacks, that says your app is not seeing the beacon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `self.locationManager.delegate = self` after instantiating the `CLLocationManager`. Otherwise delegation won't work.

Comment: thanks for that. Now didRangeBeacons gets called all the time, but with empty beacon set.

Comment: That's it. Accept the answer, and welcome to StackOverflow. I may suggest reading CLLocationmanager docs to understand which methods you need to call to fullfill your needs.